# Searching for words in a string and comparing them

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I can't come up with a word search code that would still output the word when the position of the word changes

```
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] arg)
        {

            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
            Console.InputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;

            var srd = new MultiSet<Garders>()
            {
                new Garders("ірис, троянда, айстра, півонія, жоржин"),
                new Garders("ірис, троянда, айстра, півонія, жоржин, хризантема, гладіолус"),
                new Garders("ірис, троянда, айстра, півонія, гладіолус")

            };
            MultiSet<Garders>.Enumerator e = srd.GetEnumerator();
            string[] temp = new string[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
            {
                e.MoveNext();
                temp[i] = e.Current.flower;
            }
            e.Reset();
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                
                string[] srt = e.Current.flower.Split();

                foreach (var item in srt)
                {
                    if (temp[0].Contains(item) == temp[1].Contains(item) 
                        && temp[1].Contains(item) == temp[2].Contains(item))
                            Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
                
        }

    }
}
```

My code only outputs the same words if they are in the same positions

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Its unclear

Comment: i have several plants and they should match regardless of the position of the element with the plant name, and so it coincides only when all elements are in the same position

Comment: You can solve the problem by sorting the array before comparing, e.g. `srt = srt.OrderBy( x => x).ToArray()`.  On a side note, I have never seen such a simple problem so needlessly complicated! Why are you working with enumerators directly? Why not just use `foreach`?

Comment: Such a task was set

Comment: @Exavi so in short, you want to compare all the items of your set whether they have the same sub items in the same order?

Comment: You understood everything correctly

Comment: Do you seriously need answers that *only* uses C# 3 features?

Comment: I'm not really sure, just started school

Comment: I would suggest clarification of your question, because even with your comments it is still unclear to me what is the match and what is not. So it would be good to have some examples for match and mismatch (like: container "A B C D" matches "A C", container "A B C D" matches "C A"?).

Comment: @greenoldman just like that, even using the commenter's tip above, it still doesn't show what's needed

Answer (score 0):

You have written very complex logic, it should be very easy if you read the problem statement carefully.

Based on the discussion in a comment, you want to compare two collections whether they have the same items in the same order.

You could use [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0).

and compare like this.

```
List<string> ls1 = new List<string>() { "1", "2"};
List<string> ls2 = new List<string>() { "1", "2" };
bool isEqual = ls1.SequenceEqual(ls2);
```